Story Identification with Pirates, Sand Sharks, and Chicken Leg Trees
This movie or tv show was from the mid-1990s or prior.
In one scene, a couple pirates are discussing the food growing on the various trees of the island.  One of the trees is growing chicken legs.  There are other trees that grow similar kinds of food that don't grow on trees (one example is chewing gum, but I don't remember what any of the others are).
In another scene, the main character (a boy) is being chased by a "sand shark."  Though, these sand sharks can "swim" through the sand on the island (rather than in the water).  The boy escapes the sand shark by climbing a tree that grows chewing gum.  He is able to incapacitate the shark by picking the chewing gum from the tree and throwing it in the shark's mouth.

If it's a live-action TV movie, then a good match is Magic Island (1995).  Quoting the plot summary on Wikipedia:

Jack Carlisle is a disillusioned 13-year-old boy. His mother is always away at work since his father left. He decides to run away, as he feels his mom won't miss him. As he is ready to leave, his nanny convinces him to read a 'magic book' that belongs to her.
The book is about a pirate adventure on Magic Island. As Jack reads the book, he is sucked into the world and goes on numerous adventures with Prince Morgan, while fleeing the evil Blackbeard the Pirate. He is even saved by Lily, a beautiful mermaid, whom he falls in love with.
Lily is given the power to turn into a human and accompanies Jack on his adventure. Along the way, Jack encounters sand sharks, a tree that grows the favorite food of the person who climbs it, and a cursed temple full of treasure. Jack also uses items he brought along with him in his "magic" bag to stop the pirates. Blackbeard was transformed into a gold statue by a guardian wizard.

It's not actually a chicken leg tree, though, when Jack first encounters it the tree is growing pizza slices:

But the tree is protected by a "sand shark:"

That Jack defeats by feeding it gum:


